# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request (After changing namespace)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

After changing the namespace I got the error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Details' was not found. The
> following locations were searched:
> /Areas/Customers/Views/Home/Details.cshtml
> /Areas/Customers/Views/Shared/Details.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Details.cshtml

I feel terrible because of so basic error.
As you can see here in the picture
[image: As you can see here in the picture]

[Project has been upload to here](https://github.com/nguyentuananh921/Bulky_MVC/commits/master)

Comment: What's your request like? I see your Detail view . What's Details.cshtml ?

Comment: Yes sir, so stupid question and error. Thanks.